# How to do a right join on this query based on date column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How to do right join on this query. i have another table to which i need to right join this query result based on date.

```
(SELECT t.date FROM (SELECT ("2018-01-31" - INTERVAL c.number DAY) AS date
FROM (SELECT singles + tens + hundreds number FROM 
(SELECT 0 singles
UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
) singles JOIN 
(SELECT 0 tens
UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
) tens  JOIN 
(SELECT 0 hundreds
UNION ALL SELECT  100 UNION ALL SELECT  200 UNION ALL SELECT  300
UNION ALL SELECT  400 UNION ALL SELECT  500 UNION ALL SELECT  600
UNION ALL SELECT  700 UNION ALL SELECT  800 UNION ALL SELECT  900
) hundreds
ORDER BY number DESC) c  
WHERE c.number BETWEEN 0 and 30) );
```

New query, this is the query after adding left join

```
    select date from(SELECT d.date FROM (SELECT ("2018-01-31" - INTERVAL c.number DAY) AS date
FROM (SELECT singles + tens + hundreds number FROM 
(SELECT 0 singles
UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
) singles JOIN 
(SELECT 0 tens
UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
) tens  JOIN 
(SELECT 0 hundreds
UNION ALL SELECT  100 UNION ALL SELECT  200 UNION ALL SELECT  300
UNION ALL SELECT  400 UNION ALL SELECT  500 UNION ALL SELECT  600
UNION ALL SELECT  700 UNION ALL SELECT  800 UNION ALL SELECT  900
) hundreds
ORDER BY number DESC) c  
WHERE c.number BETWEEN 0 and 30))d LEFT JOIN report r ON r.date = d.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`.  Then you simply do:

```
select d.date, . . . 
from (<your query here>) d left join
     yourtable t
     on t.date = d.date
```

Comment: Thar is not working, getting error like ever table should have its own alias though alias is given.

Comment: "Thar is not working, getting error like ever table should have its own alias though alias is given." then you are doing something else wrong the "prototype" query off Gorden is correct

Comment: i have added the query above

Comment: @user3292629 . . . The subqueries and table references in this answer all have aliases.  Your version doesn't have the alias `d` specified in this answer.

Comment: But it is givng that error "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: t is mentioned as alias

Comment: @user3292629 . . . It needs to go after the parentheses, as shown in this answer.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff see the added query

Comment: @user3292629 . . . You need an alias both inside and outside the parens.  All subqueries in the `FROM` clause need table aliases.

Comment: If this query will be run often, create a table with the values from 0 to 999. MySQL will create a temp table like that every time you run the query, so if you're going to run this more than once, it would be more efficient to have the table already created. It would also make your query more readable and maintainable.